# Passing in a large list of values into a constructor to initialise finals.

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, final

So imagine we have a situation like this:

```
public class Bar1 {
    public final int VALUE1; 
    public final double VALUE2;
    public final String NAME; 
    /*DOZENS OF FINALS!*/

    public Bar1(int v1, double v2, String name)
    {
        this.VALUE1 = v1; 
        this.VALUE2 = v2;
        this.NAME = name; 
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Foo1
{
    private Bar1 bar1;
    private Bar1 bar2;
    private Bar1 bar3;
    /*Dozens of bars!*/

    public Foo1( //We need to pass the values in here)
                 {
                     bar1 = new Bar1( //we need to initialise each of the bars. )
                     bar2 =...
                     bar3 = ...
                 }


}
```

What's a good way of doing this? I think passing each one in as it's own argument,

eg:

```
public class Foo1
{
    private Bar1 bar1;
    private Bar1 bar2;
    private Bar1 bar3;
    /*Dozens of bars!*/

    public Foo1(int bar1Value1, double bar1Value2, String bar1String, 
                        int bar2Value1, double bar2Value2, String bar2String,
                        int bar3Value1, double bar3Value2, String bar3String)
                 {
                     bar1 = new Bar1(bar1Value1, bar1Value2, bar1String);
                     bar2 = new Bar1(bar2Value1, bar2Value2, bar2String);
                     bar3 = new Bar1(bar3Value1, bar3Value2, bar3String);
                 }


}
```

is a huge pain in the ass.

I'll post the solution I've come up with, but I'm wondering what other solutions there are.

Comment: Just don't make them final and instead use a builder.

Comment: Have you considered the Builder pattern? (Ps this is not a quiz site - you should give all the relevant information).

Comment: @Adam: Why not make them final? A builder is precisely useful to build immutable objects with final fields.

Comment: @Adam Builder pattern can coexist with final fields.

Comment: @assylias I thought finals had to be initialized by time the constructor had completed... obviously could simulate final by making the object immutable, private constructor etc.

Comment: @Adam the Builder is typically a separate (for example inner) class of the class to be built which is built in one go and can have immutable fields.

Comment: See http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/apidoc/1.0-RC1/src-html/com/ninja_squad/dbsetup/operation/Insert.html for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate out your types. If you have *dozens* of fields, it's almost certain that either:

- Some of those fields are related to each other, so should be captured in their own type, e.g. if you have fields `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `city`, `state` then that should be an `Address` type
- Some of the fields aren't related at all, and shouldn't be in the same type to start with

I have never seen a well-designed class with dozens of fields.

Once you've cut down the number of fields, you won't have a problem with an unwieldy constructor.

If you *do* still have a lot of fields, the builder pattern (as mentioned in comments) is indeed good, if a little tedious: have a mutable builder type (often a nested type), and then a `build()` method which passes the builder itself to the constructor of the immutable type, which copies the values from the builder into the final fields.

Comment: The problem is that the arguements still add up. 

I'll explain using the code I'm actually trying to do: 

I have a `Parameter` class (the bars) which has `MIN` `MAX` `DEFAULT` and `NAME`. Then I have a various components (a foo) that have varying numbers of Parameters, for example `Oscillator` has `Frequency`, `Phase`, `Amp`, `Fourier`, `Curve`, `Slope`, `Width`. 

I don't want to store the final in the `Oscillator` class, because I'm not actually sure then what the MAX for frequency should be. That should be determined by the application that is using it.

Comment: @user1068446: That wasn't really a very clear explanation - *which* final do you not want to store? You definitely shouldn't have frequencyMin, frequencyMax, frequencyDefault, frequencyName, etc. It sounds like `Oscillator` could have six fields, but that's not so bad...

Comment: MIN, MAX, DEFAULT, NAME are all finals of the `Parameter` class.

- You get that for a single oscillator - I need to somewhere enter 6*4   = 24 values somewhere right?

The question is - how do I easily tell the Oscillator what it's MIN and MAX, etc values are for each of it's parameters?

Comment: Meta question here: should I perhaps just edit my question to include the actual code I'm using?

Comment: @user1068446: You pass in the 6 `Parameter` values, which you construct separately. That's the point. Instead of passing in 24 arguments in one enormous call, you break it up.

Comment: So like:

`Oscillator myOsc = new Oscillator(new Parameter(0, 100, 50, "frequency"), new Parameter(-180, 180, 0, "Phase")....)`? That does sound agreeable to me.

Comment: @user1068446: Yes, although ideally creating the new objects in previous statements, so you can use descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution. Pass the values in as a 2d array of Strings, and covert each of the String to it's corresponding type.

```
public class Foo1
{
    private Bar1 bar1;
    private Bar1 bar2;
    private Bar1 bar3;

    public Foo1(String[][] values)
    {
        Bar1[] bars = {bar1, bar2, bar3};

        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            bars[i] = new Bar1(Integer.parseInt(values[i][0]), Double.parseDouble(values[i][1]), values[i][2]); 

        }


    }

}




public class FooBar1 {

    private static final String[][] myFoo1Values = {
            //Value1, Value2, Name
            //Integer, Double, String
            {"1", "2.22", "bar 1"},
            {"2", "5.59", "BAR TWO"},
            {"333", "2", "- tre"}
    };

    static private Foo1 myFoo1; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        myFoo1 = new Foo1(myFoo1Values);

    }

}
```